# Making sure my users don't fake that they've completed a task I can not verify electronically?

Tags: game-design, rpg, economy

I hope this is worded alright, I didn't know how else to describe it. I'm developing a game that has the user set their own "missions" that take place in real life. A simple example would be "Smile at a stranger". Then they can mark it complete and win coins with which they can use to buy real prizes.

However, because these tasks cannot be verified to see if the user has *really* completed them, I'm worried that people will just mark things as complete to win coins and get prizes without working for them. I used a fitness iphone game years ago where this was the case.

How do you suggest I prevent this from happening?

**Edit**: My first thought was to add a max amount of missions a user could do a day. Something like two. And let users that subscribe (so the more serious users) have limitless missions a day.

Thank you for the suggestions so far!

Comment: Did you smile at a stranger yesterday? How would you, personally, convince me that you did? I'm not sure if that's a solvable problem outside of a dystopian AI surveillance state. ;) Do you have flexibility to change or restrict the types of missions you offer to ones that are in some way verifiable?

Comment: Heh, I see the issue. But no I don't think so; the missions are ones the user sets themselves to complete and aside from marking them as complete and other small stuff like rating difficulty, it's carried out away from the app. I've thought a lot about how I can make this less "cheatable" but can't come up with anything

Comment: You should read the book [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)! It has a lot of good inspirational ideas that could make this work!

Answer (score 1):

## Make tasks that are verifiable

"Take a picture with a stranger" can be verified: the user can upload a photo. The system doesn't need to *do* anything with this photo other than store it away somewhere. Then if a user is suspected of cheating (by a system that looks at their number of complete tasks and how long it took them to do so, etc. etc.--a much easier problem to solve using statistics) an admin/moderator can pull up all of the photos/etc. that were used as proof and do a manual check.

Another task might be to visit a landmark / particular location. They can then check in via their device (and you can request GPS coordinates). Those coordinates are spoofable (as evidenced by all the people cheating at Pokemon GO) but are as reliable as a random photo upload (again: an admin/mod can pull up the records of where they checked in, etc. etc. and see if it was plausible that they could get there).

Answer (score 1):

If the task cannot be verified, you need to rely on the user to self-verify. For this to work, the users need to be intrinsically motivated to perform the task.

**Minimise external rewards**

If you offer too much external rewards relative to the intrinsic value of the task - such as prizes for smiling at a stranger - you can decrease the intrinsic motivation for the task. This is known as the [overjustification effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overjustification_effect). And once the user becomes extrinsically motivated, they are way more likely to cheat.

If possible, minimise or offer no external rewards at all. You should focus on reinforcing the intrinsic motivation, for example via praise. Praise is a good tool to use as it is less meaningful when the user cheats. Also, don't underestimate the satisfaction of checking items off a list, or measuring progress.

**Use tasks that build toward a verifiable goal, and reward that**

For example, if you were creating a health and fitness app, you might have small, unverifiable tasks like "ate a healthy meal today". But eventually, these lead to verifiable changes, like weight loss, or being able to run a certain distance. You might not reward the unverifiable tasks but you can reward the verifiable ones. The rewards still need to be small enough to avoid encouraging cheating. It also depends on how easy it is to cheat, and how powerful the intrinsic motivation is (e.g. actually being fit and healthy) v.s. the external reward.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty implausible barring proper verification. The best I can think of is having multiple users verifying each other on different devices. This is still fairly simple to get around, but would at least provide some barrier. It also requires multiple users working together, which is both a good thing and a bad thing. On one hand, it means better virality for app distribution. On the other hand it means people who aren’t socially active wouldn’t be able to use the app.

A more lenient option would be to award a few points whenever they check something off with a maximum of one a day or something, but if they get another user to verify it, they get more points and another chance to check off something the same day.

Just remember, this is pretty simple to get around. Owning two devices is all that’s necessary. You could require a Facebook login to verify that two different accounts exist at least, and rely on Facebook’s Terms of Service to “guarantee” every person has only one account.

If these are things that can be verified with a video, you could have users upload videos of them doing whatever it is and multiple other random users can watch the videos and confirm or deny that it happened (maybe awarding points for videos you watch for other users). This would invite trolls to share NC-17 content though, so... hmm.

Comment: I like the suggestion of sharing content - especially if this app is meant to promote social positivity (as the smiling example suggests), sharing a positive or helpful video / tweet / etc. could have a positive effect outside of just the app's own users - so it can serve a purpose besides verification too. Charitable donations could be another useful vector in this respect.

Comment: Good suggestions! A social factor could definitely be added. Though some users might not want to share the challenges they are making themselves complete (say if it's something they find difficult they don't want others to know)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have the user select a minimal duration for each task, only after which they would be able to mark the task as completed.

If users are forced to live some life in between visits to the app, they may be more likely to have a try at the tasks.

Cheaters may not be patient enough to wait out even the most minimal duration in order to cheat.

This wouldn't guarantee that nobody cheats, of course, but might help "serious" users get the most out of the app.

You could also have the app ask, when the user tries to mark a task as completed, "Are you being honest with yourself?" This may not curb cheating all that much, but if this is a self-help kind of app, it might be an interestingng touch.

Comment: Great idea - it would also limit the amount of tasks you could do in a day so users wouldn't be able to rapidly stack up points in order to get a prize.